# ASP.NET Core 404 for project template with Angular 6 bundled files (wrong dist output directory)

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I've created a ASP.NET Core application with the Angular project template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

## Generated output

When deploying on IIS, the base href is `<base href="/">`

And the path of the scripts inside the generated dist/index.html are :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

## Problem : 404 errors

[image: Screenshot of the 404 when deployed on IIS]

## However C# Startup.cs should correctly set the path to the output directory

The ASP.NET Core project should be aware that these files are in the `ClientApp/dist` directory because of this code :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }
```

## Why the base path isn't set correctly ?

The project runs on IIS, we can see the background initialisation message of index.html appear correctly, however as shown in the picture, all resources are loaded on the root "/" of the server, so they get 404's.

If I try to load http://{SERVERIP}/{PROJECTNAMEHERE}/runtime.js I see that it works, so I guess that it's probably only a matter of **base href**.

How to set that base href dynamically from ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am having the same issue. The project run fine in IIS express as it run directly in localhost:port but fails to load js file when published. By default VS publishes ClientApp on the root folder outside wwwroot. I also tried move the ClientApp folder to wwwroot, tried setting base-href but nothing is working.

Comment: Does anyone has solution to this? I encountered the same issue.  If I moved the files into the wwwroot folder it worked fine.  So, I'm wondering about how we could make it to work inside the ClientApp/dist.  This is working before in that folder and suddently it didn't work.

Comment: I figured it out. It worked after I added this line app.UseSpaStaticFiles(); inside the Configure method in Startup.cs

Answer (score 6):

I continued having this issue after taking Setrákus advice on including this line in my Startup.cs file

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
}
```

So after some trial and error, I found the following worked for me:

- Delete the dist folder in ClientApp
- Run an angular build command that specifies the websites base href, for example if my intended destination was http://localhost/ABC then I would run

  ```
  'ng build --base-href /ABC/'
  ```

**This handled the angular application but there is a change needed on the .NET Core side too.**

Looking at some similar issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1514) it seemed like the call to enable the angular cli middleware **UseAngularCliServer()** was causing the issue.

To remove the UseAngularCliServer() call You can simply comment it out like below if your just testing, or if this is for a proper hosting environment, change the [ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environments) environment variable to "Production" to skip that if block.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       //spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Angular 6 introduced the feature of multiple projects per workspace (see [this](https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/angular-6-angular-cli-workspaces/)), and each project is compiled to a sub-folder inside dist/, however the ASP.NET core angular template works with Angular 5 which compiles immediately inside dist/.

So one way to solve this: open angular.json and change "outputPath" value from `dist/<your project name>` to simply `dist`

Answer (score 2):

**You don't need to do anything just replace base href inside**

> /src/index.html

**Before**

```
<base href="/">
```

**After**

```
<base href="/YOURSITENAMEHERE/">
```

Then publish asp.net Core Site.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to expand a bit more on the answer by @tahasultantemuri which I think is correct.  The only issue is if the index.html file is edited match the production location of your site then after publishing it will have to be changed back or running on local host will no longer work.  To avoid this, modify your .csproj file as follows

**Before**

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
   ...
   <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
   ...
</Target>
```

**After**

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
   ...
   <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod --base-href /site name/>
   ...
</Target>
```

The local host version of the index.html file will be retained for debugging.