# Pass additional parameter to npm run in .csproj file

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, dotnet-cli

Just came across this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149896/asp-net-core-404-for-project-template-with-angular-6-bundled-files-wrong-dist-o) (Briefly: After deploy a freshly generated dotnet core anuglar app to an IIS instance got 404 for all the .css and .js files) and found that the first answer is working for me. When build the app with `--base-href <basedir>` option 404s disappears, app starts working.

What I want to archive currently is that `dotnet publish` would do this to me automatically per publish profile (so hardcode the base-href to .csproj is not an option here). The way I thought to make this work is that I've added a new property to the *profile.pubxml.user* file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <additionalBuildParams>--base-href /myapp/</additionalBuildParams>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

And modified the .csproj file like:

```xml
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
...
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build $(additionalBuildParams) --prod" />
...
</Target>
```

but after executing `dotnet publish -c Debug /p:PublishProfile=profile.pubxml`
 the output looks like this:

```
λ dotnet publish -c Debug /p:PublishProfile=profile.pubxml
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
...
  > MyApp@0.0.0 build C:\Projects\MyApp
  > ng build --extract-css "/myapp/"
```

Obviously the desired output would be:

```
  > ng build --extract-css --base-href /myapp/
```

Comment: Additionally: If I simply echo out the parameter like `<Exec Command='echo $(additionalBuildParams)' />` the output is the expected value: `--base-href /myapp/` so it must be something with how dotnet cli passes the property to npm run. The corresponding part of packate.json looks like this BTW: `"build": "ng build --extract-css"`

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the question. You want to run `npm run` but in the output the command is `ng build` so you don't expect you argument will added to the `ng build`. did you understand me?

Comment: @Baruch: I did. Added a comment above to clarify the scenario because of this. Basically what happens here is dotnet publish cli executes the `<Exec ...` line with the command `npm run build $(additionalBuildParams) --prod`. And you can see in the comment that it's gonna translated to `ng build --extract-css` and passes all the parameters comes after, but for some reason it filters out everything starting with `--` and also put double quotes before and after the rest of the property.